# How do I make the inner edge parallel to the outer edge?

Tags: modeling

I want the inner edge to be parallel to the outer edge. How do I do it? I tried Vertex Slide but it is still not completely parallel.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl E > Offset Edges > Extrude then tweak the values in the Operator box

Comment: To preserve the original edges, I think only a Python script will work. You could use Mesh Tools to set edge length on the edges connecting the inner and outer loop, but that won't make the pairs of edges parallel, only roughly parallel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delete the inner loop, only leave the outer loop.
2. Press  <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the face.
3. Press  <kbd>I</kbd> to inset face.
4. Delete what you don't need.

If you don't want to delete the origin edge,you can creat a copy object,do like what I do on the copy,and then snap the vertice to the copy one by one manually.

If there are too many vertice or the model is too complicated,how to fix it depends on the model,case by case.
[image]

Comment: Yes i can do that but is there a way to make the edge parallel? I don't want to delete the edge. This is just an example and I can't share the real model file. Which has a lot of vertices connected to each other.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the origin edge,you can creat a copy object,do like what I do on the copy,and then snap the vertice to the copy one by one manually.